# Xalan performance issue when using call-template parameters

Tags: xslt-1.0, xalan

It seems that exists an performance issue with a call-template parameters when exceeding 1024 parameters(the CPU and memory are overloaded). It's there an workaround to fix this when you have more then 1024 added parameters?

I will add more information's about it when i will receive them.
The issue doesn't exist when using Saxon but i need to use Xalan as processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the parameters in a node-set and pass that in your call-template.  This is an example, but you can set it up any way you want.  You could also use xml:element to create the parameter elements.  (Or, you can make these variables global and not pass anything.  Just access them from your template.)

```
<xsl:variable name="parameters">
  <parameters>
    <parm name="name1">value1</parm>
    <parm name="name2">value2</parm>
    <parm name="name3">value3</parm>
  </parameters>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- For 1.0 -->
<xsl:variable name"parameterList"  select="msxml:node-set($parameters)"/>
```